# Can I break values into buckets?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, math, statistics

I have a two column dataframe of names and purchase value. Is there any way I can cluster them in 25% buckets them to show how much of the total value they make.

So the top 25% of sales by value make up 50% of all revenue

I've already grouped and sorted by values by smallest to largest

```
df = df.sort_values(['purchase_value'], ascending=[True])
```

I want a table output that shows:

### Group     % of total revenue

top 25% - 56%

second 25% - 25%

lower 25% - 15%

bottom 25% - 4%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` provides some convenient statistics functions that you can use to achieve what you need. In particular, [numpy.percentile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html?highlight=percentile#numpy.percentile) and [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram).

```py
import numpy as np

# 100 random numbers for testing purposes
values = np.random.rand(100)
# values = np.array(df.purchase_value)

# Get the values on the boundary of each percentile
q_list = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100]
percentiles = list(np.percentile(values, q_list))

# Sum the values in the bin between each pair of percentiles
bin_sums = np.histogram(values, bins=percentiles, weights=values)[0]

# Normalize by the total amount of value
bin_percents = 100 * bin_sums / np.sum(bin_sums)

# Output
for left, right, percent in zip(q_list[:-1], q_list[1:], bin_percents):
    print("Portion of value between {}% and {}%: {}%".format(left, right, percent))

# Portion of value between 0% and 25%: 6.7259763107428965%
# Portion of value between 25% and 50%: 17.0792197951553%
# Portion of value between 50% and 75%: 31.52807116533235%
# Portion of value between 75% and 100%: 44.66673272876946%
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I get an odd error that says 100% of revenue falls in the top 75-100%

Comment: @Cheese-Lord can you provide some example values for which this occurs?

Comment: @Cheese-Lord Start from the output you want and work backwards: (1) How do you calculate that 56% of the value comes from the top 25% of values? Sum up the values in the top 25% and divide by the total value. (2) How do I find which values are in the top 25%? They should be larger than the 25%th largest value (the 25th percentile). (3) How do I find the 25%th largest value in python? `numpy.percentile`